# HTTP ERROR 500 in wordpress while downloading PDF

Tags: wordpress

Error - is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500 in wordpress while downloading  PDF

Comment: nany one tell me how to reslove it?

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 is not realy helpfull. Maybe there is more information in the error log file or enable debug mode for display errors.